# Activity performance with conditional visibility gone/visible

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a fragment that contains a `LinearLayout` that is conditionnaly displayed or not. In terms of performance what is the best? Mark the `LinearLayout` as `android:visibility="gone"` in the XML, and then in code I set its visibility if needed, or the opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inflating a layout with some views with a visibility set to GONE is bad for performances, especially if the view is a bit complex.**

check url :[http://magicmicky.github.io/android_development/benchmark-using-traceview/](http://%20Inflating%20a%20layout%20with%20some%20views%20with%20a%20visibility%20set%20to%20GONE%20is%20bad%20for%20performances,%20especially%20if%20the%20view%20is%20a%20bit%20complex.%20check%20url%20http://magicmicky.github.io/android_development/benchmark-using-traceview/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless that layout is very complex and has too many views, I wouldn't worry about it, it won't matter very much.

But it does seem more logical to initially set it to be `gone` unless you decide that it should be `visible` afterwards.

You could also think of it from a UX point of view, should the user see it very briefly then it disappears? or should it work the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing much with the performance in these two implementation unless you are hiding the layout after a long running network calls or something like this which requires some time to make the decision of hiding and showing the layout or the layout is too complex.

However, I would suggest you to keep the following things in mind.

1. In case of orientation changes of your activity, you need to handle the layout visibility in your `onCreate` or `onResume` function as the activity gets recreated. If you are hiding the layout and not keeping a track of it in a global static variable, the decision might get lost and you might get inconsistency in your overall layout design. However, if you are hiding your `LinearLayout` based on a decision which is being made in your `onCreate` function, you will not face this exact situation.
2. If this `LinearLayout` is inside an item of your `RecyclerView` or `ListView`, think of handling each of your layouts items carefully.